# YMLto html table in blogdown / hugo

Tags: r, hugo, blogdown

I've found several examples ([1](https://statsf18.classes.andrewheiss.com/schedule/),[2](http://www2.stat.duke.edu/courses/Spring18/Sta199/syllabus/),[3](https://espm-157.carlboettiger.info/syllabus)) of blogdown websites that have tabular data stored in a  *.yml file, which is converted to a tabular structure in the final website. I would like to reconstruct this method to adapt the table to my personal needs, but I don't even know where to begin looking. Where does this magic happen?

In the example of [1](https://statsf18.classes.andrewheiss.com/schedule/), the file [lessons.yml](https://github.com/andrewheiss/statsf18.classes.andrewheiss.com/blob/dabe37c12962236e58b62677e1374892d2d78d22/data/lessons.yml) holds the data, rendering it to the output below
[image: lessons.yml]

---

[image]